# In Vim, can I yank from a specific character behind the cursor to another after the cursor?

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm on the following line, and the vertical bar represents my cursor:

```
<div class="|foo">Some text</div>
```

I need to copy the whole start tag my cursor is currently on (`<div class="foo">`),  but then I need to change the `class` value, so I don't want to move my cursor after the yank is complete. Is there a command to copy **from** `<` **to** `>` - something like `F<yf>`, but without losing my place in the line?

Answer (score 3):

```
ya<
```

yanks `<div class="foo">` and moves the cursor to `<`. See `:help text-objects`.

To move the cursor back to where it was before, use ``` :help `` ```:

```
ya<``
```

Comment: Oh of course, I forgot that < counts as a text object! That solves my specific issue - what if, for example, I wanted to copy from < to the first " after the cursor? I assume there's no more efficient solution than `F<y2f"`?

Comment: No, the text object is `a<`, not `<`. I find counting very unintuitive so, in this case, I would probably do something like `f"yvF<` instead.